# Commands in Java Console

Tags: java, linux, shell, unix, bittorrent

I'm trying to automate creating torrents/starting downloads/limiting Bandwidth... etc using Vuze.

So far I've written a shell script to send Vuze and the torrent to all the clients. However when it comes to creating torrents, after executing this command : **java -jar Azureus2-XXX.jar --ui=console** or **java -jar Azureus2-XXX.jar --ui=console &**, the console looks like this and no command after that works unless I quit the Java program.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you cannot interact with the program's CLI if you background it via `&`. Maybe you should state your higher level goals. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried even without &. I'm trying to code a script for creating a torrent for example. I wrote the script 
#!/bin/bash
java -jar Azureus2-XXX.jar --ui=console
create file file.torrent udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80' 

But that last command won't work.

Comment: you need to learn how the command line/shell scripts work in general. This is neither specific to java nor to bittorrent. parameters are not the same as standard input / output.

Comment: Thank you I've found the answer, there is this option on java -jar : --exec
I've created a file with the commands I'm going to execute and ran this command : **java -jar Azureus2-XXX.jar --ui=console --exec=(path to file)** and it worked :D